# How can i get a pid of a process generated by cmd line?

Tags: c#, cmd, pid

I want to know how to get a pid of a process started by cmd instruction.

Here's an example

```
string instruction = "mpiexec FDTD.exe";

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
System.Diagnostics.Process pro = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

proInfo.FileName = @"cmd";
proInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
proInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

proInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

pro.StartInfo = proInfo;

richTextBox1.AppendText("FDTD Simulation Starts\n");
pro.Start();

pro.StandardInput.Write(temp + Environment.NewLine);
pro.StandardInput.Write(instruction + Environment.NewLine);
pro.StandardInput.Close();
```

According to the code above, I started FDTD.exe using cmd line.
However, i can't find the way to get FDTD.exe's pid.

Is there anybody can help me out?

thx in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you starting cmd.exe to start FDTD.exe? Why not just start FDTD directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) and the [`Process.Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id.aspx) property to get the PID(s). If there's just one FDTD.exe running, this is simple:

```
int pid = Process.GetProcessesByName("FTDT").Single().Id;
```

If there are multiple, you'll need some way to choose the best one. I don't know of a sure way, but your scenario might work by finding a process that was started at the right time ([`Duration()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gets the absolute value of the `TimeSpan`):

```
DateTime targetTime = DateTime.Now;

pro.StandardInput.Write(temp + Environment.NewLine);
pro.StandardInput.Write(instruction + Environment.NewLine);
pro.StandardInput.Close();

Process[] fdtdProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("FTDT");
int pid = fdtdProcs
            .OrderBy(x => (x.StartTime - targetTime).Duration()).First().Id;
```

Or by recording the PIDs before and after:

```
var pidsBefore = Process.GetProcessesByName("FTDT").Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

pro.StandardInput.Write(temp + Environment.NewLine);
pro.StandardInput.Write(instruction + Environment.NewLine);
pro.StandardInput.Close();

var pidsAfter = Process.GetProcessesByName("FTDT")
                       .Select(x => x.Id)
                       .Except(pidsBefore);
int pid = pidsAfter.Single();
```

Comment: And will this be the ID of `cmd.exe`, or the launched `FDTD.exe`?

Comment: I've updated my code with some potential ways to support multiple, and to get the PID of `FDTD.exe` instead of `cmd.exe`.