# Net Framework - WaitForExit not working because I can't determine svchost.exe PID

Tags: process, pid, .net-4.8, windows-task-scheduler, waitforexit

I need to show the Windows Task Scheduler window and wait until the user closes it before continuing the main program.

I've tried with this method:

```
public static bool RunCommand (string command)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Verb = "runas",
                Arguments = "/C " + command,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            Process process = new();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I've tried passing the following commands as the argument "command" in order to show up the Task Scheduler:

- "taskschd.msc"
- "start /wait taskschd.msc /s"
- "C:\windows\system32\taskschd.msc /s"
- "control schedtasks"

The idea is to continue the execution of the main program when the Task Scheduler is closed (its process is killed), but the "process.WaitForExit();" instruction is linked to the cmd command, so the main program continues after cmd process is closed, even when the Task Scheduler window is still being displayed.

The problem is that the "taskschd.msc" process, when launched, is wrapped into an "svchost.exe" process. I can't determine its PID because of the many different svchosts running at the same time, so I can't kill it manually either.

I've tried [the solutions proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486028/how-can-i-get-a-pid-of-a-process-generated-by-cmd-line), but to no avail.

I've also been looking for a way to give an alias to the the "scvhost.exe" process launched with this cmd, but it seems that's not possible.

I've been thinking of compiling a new exe just to launch the Task Scheduler under a process name that I could control, but I don't think it is a good solution.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Actually, launching it through cmd.exe was the first option. I've also tried launching directly "taskschd.msc", but the problem is the same: since it's wrapped into a svchost process, I can't control when it's closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching taskschd.msc through mmc.exe works:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "mmc.exe",
    Arguments = "taskschd.msc",
    Verb = "runas",
    UseShellExecute = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};
var process = Process.Start(psi);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. This solution has the same problem as the "cmd": once the Task Scheduler GUI is displayed, mmc.exe process is killed, so the main program (which launched mmc) would continue. I'd like it to be paused until the Task Scheduler windows is closed by the user.

Comment: Please provide a reproduction case. It works for me on a .NET 6 project with Windows 11 as the OS.

Comment: It's easy to reproduce: I put all your code in one single method. Afther the line that calls it, I put a MessageBox. I expect the MessageBox would only be displayed when the task scheduler is closed, but no, the WaitForExit is ignored.

Comment: @garciafigueres If it's so easy, why does it [work for me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbZMLuyo7Tk) when I do as you say? I [also tried WinForms](https://youtu.be/LgEn6fZ0MZE) - same result: works fine.

Comment: @garciafigueres I've also never seen what you are describing. `mmc.exe` remains open, I actually have it running now. `svchost` is unlikely to be involved, it's generally for services, not GUI apps. I think you might be mixing something up.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, thanks for your time. I didn't mean to bother you, sorry. I've just tried it in Net 6 and, as you say, it works flawlessly. Problem is migrating the whole solution to Net 6 is not an option right now. However, I'm very thankful for your efforts :-)

Comment: If you're running .NET Framework and this is only an issue on .NET Framework, you should probably tag `[.net]` on your question.